# I have a router running DD-WRT, plus a modem/router running OpenWAG. How can I automatically send a request every time my external IP address changes?

Tags: router, wireless-router, dd-wrt, static-routes

I have a Linksys WRT54GL with DD-WRT installed, and Linksys WAG200G with OpenWAG.

I want to send a wget request to a specific server that will automatically update my ip in their records, every-time my router's external IP address gets changed.

Currently i have a cron job to send every X hour but that is really bad and usually doesn't do the trick, which makes do it manually more often that it is useful.

I don't mind changing the firmware if other one had a feature that i could use to achieve this.

Comment: Have you tried using [No-IP Free Dynamic DNS](http://www.noip.com/free)? "Additionally, use our free dynamic DNS update client to keep track of your dynamic IP address. "

Comment: @DavidPostill That won't solve the problem

Comment: Why do you want this external server to always know your external IP address?